# Trigger insertion failure

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a invoice__c custom object with Account__c lookup field (data type -Lookup(Account)). Through API, receiving lookup field input value as account name instead of salesforce Id. I need to compare and get salesforce Id for the Account__c name((Field label - Account Name, Field Name-Name data type -Name) from Account object and insert into invoice__c account lookup field. For this I have written below trigger and got an error as "Account: id value of incorrect type". Looks issue in name to ID conversion.

Could some one correct me the below code.

```
 trigger invoiceAccountInsert on invoice__c (before insert) {
   Set<String> accountNames = new Set<String>();
   Map<String, Id> accountNameToId = new Map<String, Id>();
   for(invoice__c record: Trigger.new) {
     accountNames.add(record.Account__c);
     System.debug('Account__c >>>>>>' + record.Account__c);
   }

   list<Account> acclist = new list<Account>();
   acclist = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :accountNames]; 

   for(Account acc:acclist)
   {
    accountNameToId.put(acc.Name, acc.Id);
    System.debug('acc.Name >>>>>>' + acc.Name);
    System.debug('acc.Id >>>>>>' + acc.Id);
    System.debug('accountNameToId >>>>>>' + accountNameToId);
   }
   insert acc;
}
```

Comment: In addition to Davids answer. Just a suggestion, remove the insertion from loop.

Comment: Thank you Ysr for your suggestion. I tried with that way but no luck. Might be different issue. Will check it.

Comment: Could you please let me know-

Comment: Could you please let me know why you doing this - you're retrieving account from query and inserting again (which are already present in db)

Comment: I assume you replaced name with Id in where part

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this. Sorry, I am new to this apex programming. My requirement is, need to compare the account name value and retrieve the salesforce Id from Account object and then insert into Account__c lookup field in invoice__c object

Comment: @Djs, your code is using the `Account__c` field as containing the account's name, but you are also saying that this is a lookup field. You cannot do this in Salesforce. If `Account__c` is a lookup to Account, the only legal values are `null` or a valid Salesforce Id. You cannot import text data into Salesforce in that field.

Comment: David, I am repeating my question if it is not clear.  I have a custom object called invoice__c with field Account__c  (data type -Lookup(Account)). The lookup field stores only salesforce Id of Account. Though external API sends input for the lookup field as Account name instead of Id, I need compare the input value with Account object name field and insert the respective valid salesforce Id into Account__c lookup field of invoice__c object.

Comment: You can't do that. Salesforce validates foreign keys (lookup fields) before the data even gets to your trigger. If you send data in a lookup field other than an Id, Salesforce will throw an error and there is nothing you can do to change that. You will need to change your data model or your integration.

Comment: @David, Got it. Thank you. Will look for other approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot populate a value other than a valid Salesforce Id in a lookup field. You will need to bring in your account names for matching in a separate field that is of type Text, and populate the lookup field only when you locate the correct Salesforce Id.

Salesforce validates foreign keys (lookup fields) before the data even gets to your trigger. If you send data in a lookup field other than an Id, Salesforce will throw an error immediately. You will need to change your data model to make Account__c a Text field or change your integration to send the Name data in a different field.

Comment: Thank you David for the information. Current data type is name. Will this not work with 'name' data type? I have only option is by comparing the input value with name and insert the corresponding salesforce Id into lookup field. It would be great if you could share any other options or example to make it work.

Comment: @Djs, would you please edit your question to make clear the names and data types of all of the fields involved?